# remove few dates from date range

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2015, 12, 20)
end_dt = date(2016, 1, 11)
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

I have date range as above stated, but I have few dates from this date range to ignore. These dates are in dataframe.

How can I take these dates out from this date range? Anyone please suggest. Dataframe with distinct dates are below.

```
Pardata = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/Test/data.parquet")
Pardata.createOrReplaceTempView("parfile")
ParRes = spark.sql("SELECT distinct date FROM parfile  ")
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: try doing this with normal Python constructs. This is not a good usecase for Pyspark. How many dates are we talking about? From the first year AD till now, then we’re still talking about ± 740k dates, which can be efficiently dealt with by standard Python.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left_anti` join:

```
dates = [[dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt)]
dates_df = spark.createDataFrame(dates, ["date"])

dates_df.join(ParRes, dates_df("date") === ParRes("date"), "left_anti").show()
```

First, create a DataFrame `dates_df` from that range of dates. Then use `left_anti` join, which filters out dates from `ParRes` Dataframe in the `dates_df` Dataframe according to the key `date`.